# Unable to find an entry point named 'DllBidEntryPoint' in DLL 'System.Data.dll'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bids, entry-point, system.data

I have a project in MVC .we use EntityFrameWork.core for connection to database and use SqlServer as DataBase .In  Debug Mode every thing is ok. but when we published the project we faced to an exception. the Message of exception that was in log's file is **"Unable to find an entry point named 'DllBidEntryPoint' in DLL 'System.Data.dll'"**. what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this problem in a project (sometimes it worked and sometime it had an error for connecting to sql server) and we changed EF core to EF (downgrade EF version) and the problem is solved , I think we have a problem in version of EF (maybe project is MVC not MVC Core and It caused this problem), in addition I heard about dll 32bit in local version and 64bit in publish version and this maybe caused this problem